# Bulk image download from piwigo-based web gallery

Tags: 14.04, command-line, scripts, downloads, websites

I wish to download original sized images from this website, built upon piwigo CM http://mermaid.pink/

Single image download is allowed, but that would take ages.

Is there an application, extension, script or anything else capable of this task?

Comment: Use `wget` and http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget

Comment: Seems to be working pretty well, although it downloads much unnecessary data. Well, after all, "melius abundare quam deficere"

Comment: If you post this as an answer, I'll assign the point to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wget` as shown [here](http://linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget):

> ### Downloading an Entire Web Site with wget
>
> *Sep 05, 2008  By Dashamir Hoxha  in HOW-TOs*
>
> If you ever need to download an entire Web site, perhaps for off-line
>   viewing, wget can do the job—for example:
>
> ```
> $ wget \
>      --recursive \
>      --no-clobber \
>      --page-requisites \
>      --html-extension \
>      --convert-links \
>      --restrict-file-names=windows \
>      --domains website.org \
>      --no-parent \
>          www.website.org/tutorials/html/
> ```
>
> This command downloads the Web site
>   http://www.website.org/tutorials/html/.
>
> The options are:
>
> - `--recursive`: download the entire Web site.
> - `--domains website.org`: don't follow links outside website.org.
> - `--no-parent`: don't follow links outside the directory tutorials/html/.
> - `--page-requisites`: get all the elements that compose the page (images, CSS and so on).
> - `--html-extension`: save files with the .html extension.
> - `--convert-links`: convert links so that they work locally, off-line.
> - `--restrict-file-names=windows`: modify filenames so that they will work in Windows as well.
> - `--no-clobber`: don't overwrite any existing files (used in case the download is interrupted and resumed).

Out of these `--page-requisites` & `--recursive` will likely be needed, though `--convert-links` or `--no-clobber` may be useful. For more information on using `wget` run `man wget` (or look [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)).

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution for this as your question **get the images**

So first create the folder to save the images, then cd into it

```
#terminal
mkdir imagesFolder
cd imagesFolder/

# this one will take a long time but will download 
# every single image related to this website
wget -r -nd -H -p -A '*.jpg','*.jpeg','*.png' -e robots=off http://mermaid.pink/

#I recomend to use this one better as the images in this site are all jpg
# And recursion level is set to 1
wget -r -l 1 -nd -H -p -A '*.jpg' -e robots=off http://mermaid.pink/
```

#### The wget arguments explained:

- **-r | --recursive:**

  - Turn on recursive retrieving.    The default maximum depth is 5.
- **-l depth | --level=depth:**

  - Specify recursion maximum depth level depth.
- **-nd | --no-directories:**

  - Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving
       recursively.  With this option turned on, all files will get saved
       to the current directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up
       more than once, the filenames will get extensions .n).
- **-H | --span-hosts:**

  - Enable spanning across hosts when doing recursive retrieving.
- **-p | --page-requisites:**

  - This option causes Wget to download all the files that are
       necessary to properly display a given HTML page.  This includes
       such things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets...
- **-A | --accept:**

  - Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to
       accept. Note that if any of the wildcard characters, *,
       ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist , it will be
       treated as a pattern, rather than a suffix.  In this case, you have
       to enclose the pattern into quotes to prevent your shell from
       expanding it, like in -A "*.mp3" or -A '*.mp3'.
- **-e | --execute:**

  - Execute command as if it were a part of .wgetrc.  A command thus
       invoked will be executed after the commands in .wgetrc, thus taking
       precedence over them.  If you need to specify more than one wgetrc
       command, use multiple instances of -e.
  - In this case the **robots=off** is the argument of ***-e***

#### For more info in wget type in terminal

```
man wget
```

#### OR check [THIS](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

**Thanks *[T04435](https://github.com/T04435)***